# Syntax Error on Create Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_trx_tmp_on_transaction_update AFTER UPDATE ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.trx_status = 1 AND ( NEW.cat_id = 'CASHBACK' || NEW.cat_id = 'REFUND') THEN
        INSERT INTO trx_tmp( `id`, `trx_id`, `user_id`, `trx_merchant_trxid`, `trx_amount`, `amount_left`, `cat_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` ) VALUES ( NULL, NEW.id, NEW.userid, NEW.trx_merchant_trxid, NEW.trx_amount, NEW.trx_amount, NEW.cat_id, NOW(), NOW() );
    END IF;
END
```

I can't find where I'm doing wrong:

> [ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the command delimiter that the client is looking for in order to split commands:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER new_trx_tmp_on_transaction_update AFTER UPDATE ON transaction
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.trx_status = 1 AND ( NEW.cat_id = 'CASHBACK' || NEW.cat_id = 'REFUND') THEN
        INSERT INTO trx_tmp( `id`, `trx_id`, `user_id`, `trx_merchant_trxid`, `trx_amount`, `amount_left`, `cat_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` ) VALUES ( NULL, NEW.id, NEW.userid, NEW.trx_merchant_trxid, NEW.trx_amount, NEW.trx_amount, NEW.cat_id, NOW(), NOW() );
    END IF;
END
$$
```

The default is a semi-colon, hence it complaining at the end of the `INSERT` line when you try and create your trigger.

It's all explained in the documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html).

Comment: `[ERROR in query 1]` means that the author creates trigger via some client which differs from standard command-line mysql.exe, and it may not support delimiter changing command...